# How to Add Value to a DataGrid that has a ComboBox Column

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, combobox

What i'm trying to do is collect the data base on the referrence of DocNumber and put it in a DataGrid the record can sometimes be single to many. dependes on how it takes by retrieving. here is my function code below:

```
internal void SelectDetailsRecord(string p) 
{
    SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext();
    try
    {
        var DetailsRec = SFC.Sales_OrderFormDetails.Where(w => w.OrderDocNum == p)
            .Select(t => new { 
                    Ord = t.OrderDocNum,
                    Line = t.LineNumber,
                    Vcode = t.VariantCode,
                    Vdesc = t.VariantDesc,
                    Icode = t.Itemnmbr,
                    Idesc = t.ItemDesc,
                    Qty = t.Quantity,
                    UofM = t.UofM,
                    Kgs = t.KgsPerBag,
                    Post = t.Posted
            });
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var r in DetailsRec) 
        {
            decimal TotalKgs = Convert.ToDecimal(r.Qty) * Convert.ToDecimal(r.Kgs);
            string[] row = 
            { 
                r.Qty.ToString(), 
                r.Icode, 
                r.Idesc, 
                r.UofM, 
                r.Vcode, 
                r.Vdesc, 
                r.Kgs.ToString(), 
                TotalKgs.ToString(), 
                r.Line.ToString() 
            };

            //DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row); <-- Tried this one but returns me an error statement.

            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = row[0];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = row[1]; <-- this Part here is the combo box column
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value = row[2];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value = row[3];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[4].Value = row[4];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[5].Value = row[5];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[6].Value = row[6];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[7].Value = row[7];
            DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[8].Value = row[8];

            count++;
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    SFC.Connection.Close();
}
```

Is there a way I could put the value of the record into the datagrid combobox like putting a value in a combobox like this: " ComboBox.Text = Value; " please help if anytone has an idea.

Comment: So `DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1]` contains a ComboBox whose DataSource is row[1]?

Comment: row[1] is the value that i have retrieve from a database linq query i place it to a string so i could put a 1 row of data equal to a datagrid columns 1 row. but each DataGrid row containts 1 column of a combobox type which is cell[1] and others are just textbox.

Comment: Show code for binding grid combobox.

Comment: to Ankush Madankar i didn't code the grid combobox source i just add it by edit column on datagrid then change the source ref to a store procedure with a valuemember ref of the itemnmbr of a record in the store procedure i also created a dataset which i put my store procedure. is it ok to practice using dataset with it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate a ComboBox with a List of items, you need to set its DataSource.

```
myComboBox.DataSource = myList;
```

See the relevant MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This code must work in this problem:

```
 DataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
```

You have to convert `object` value into `string` value to set value in `GridComboBox`. Also make sure that value of `row[1]` present in collection `GridComboBox`

Comment: it's still not working it says something regarding to it's index but i check the record it has same data exist in combobox selection so it shouldn't be a -1 selection. but it still says its a -1

Comment: @John Which type of value `row[1]` has, is it is `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex`?